# Android TextView Define position of forced newline

Tags: java, android, textview

In my application, Im having a Textview containing text in this style:

```
"123131 (Ø 374)"
```

On small devices, the text reaches the viewborder causing a new line at one of these spaces. In some cases, this makes the text look like this:

```
"123131 (Ø
374)"
```

Is there a way to force the new line to the first whitespace without using 2 TextViews? Isnt there some kind of "protected white space" or something like this?

```
"123131
(Ø 374)"
```

regards
danijoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by recplacing all whitespaces but one with the unicode code for a nonbreaking whitespace:

```
"123131 (Ø\u00a0374)"
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is:

Implement a custom TextView with a listener when Ellipsis is triggered:
http://thanksmister.com/2012/10/16/android-textview-with-ellipsis-listener/

Then, when receiveing the listener, programmatically adding a '\n' character right before the '(' character.

Remember to set that TextView to be multi line.